# Function pointer in iOS?

Tags: iphone, macos, ios

Anybody can tell me about Function pointer in iOS? Thanks :D

Comment: That's an odd and unclear question.  Function pointers are a concept of a programming language, with little relation to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand properly what you are thinking of.

**1. Like in C**

```
void yourfunc() {}

foo(&yourfunc);
```

**2. In Objective-C**
You can "refer" to a method using @selector and method sig

```
- (void) test:(NSInteger)n withTest:(BOOL)isTrue {}

[object performSelector:@selector(test:withTest:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the Objective C programming environment of iOS, Objective C is a pure superset of plain ANSI C.  So function pointers work exactly the same as in C, and you can use them that same way in your iOS Objective C code.

Pointers to methods (selectors) are something somewhat different though.

Comment: A selector is emphatically not a pointer to a method. It's just a name. A pointer to a method *is* a function pointer.

Comment: Correction noted.  Selectors are different.